# how to split a string and build an associative array php?

Tags: php, wordpress, split

How to split a string in PHP ? For example, if i have the string like

```
Array([0] => "1=>10,2=>9,3=>7,1=>9,2=>8,3=>7");
```

how can i get

```
Array([0] => 1=>10,2=>9,3=>7 [1] => 1=>9,2=>8,3=>7);
```

and later i want to build an associative array like for example,

```
$ratings = array(6533 => ['Build Quality' => [1=>10,2=>9,3=>7], 
                         'Versatility' => [1=>9,2=>8,3=>7], 
                         'value' => [1=>9.5,2=>7,3=>6]]); 

//takes the current post id and returns an product ratings array                  
function get_ratings($current_post_id){

     $product_post = get_post($current_post_id);
     preg_match_all("/\[v360_product_table\s.*?\]/", $product_post>post_content, $product_elements);

     $product_elements = $product_elements[0][0];
     preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/', $product_elements, $parameters);
     $product_params = $parameters[0][0];
     $rating_params = preg_split('","', $product_params);
     $rating_factors = str_replace('"', '', $rating_params);
     $b = print_r($rating_factors);
    /* output: Array ( [0] => Build Quality [1] => Versatality [2] => Adoptability) */

     $product_rank = $parameters[0][1]; 
     /* output: Array ( [0] => 1=>10,2=>9,3=>7,1=>9,2=>8,3=>7 )  */ 
     $rank_split = preg_split('"**have to split it here**"', $product_rank);
     $rank_values = str_replace('"', '', $rank_split);

     $assoc_array = array_combine($rating_factors, $rank_values);
     /* needs to construct an array like '$ratings'  */
     $ratings = array(6533 => ['Build Quality' => [1 => 10, 2 => 8, 3 => 7], 
     'Versatility' => [1 => 9, 2 => 9, 3 => 8], 'Value' => [1 => 10, 2 => 8,3 => 8]]);
     return $ratings[$current_post_id];
        }
```

Comment: What are the rules under which you split an array - it's not clear in your question.  Also can you put any code you've tried so far.

Comment: Where is this come from `'value' => [1=>9.5,2=>7,3=>6]`?

Comment: also can you tell us where the initial string is coming from? might be easier to change that...

Comment: You can split a string in PHP using the `explode()` function. I'd recommend first splitting on `,` to get each individual key/value pair, then looping over them and splitting each on `=>` to separate the key from the value. Then you can use those to build the array you want.

Comment: i have tried with preg_split(regex pattern), str_split(after x characters) and explode(, delimiter) but couldn't able to achieve in the format how i mentioned. Any rule can be applied but need to get in this format.

Comment: Is the follow up array always in groups of 3\?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your examples, I'm guessing you want to split the string by commas followed by the number 1. To do this, you can use `preg_split()` with a positive lookahead:

```
$string = "1=>10,2=>9,3=>7,1=>9,2=>8,3=>7";
$split = preg_split('/,(?=1\b)/', $string);
var_dump($split);
```

Gives:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "1=>10,2=>9,3=>7"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "1=>9,2=>8,3=>7"
}
```

This function will parse out the whole string into a nested array:

```
function split_string($string)
{
    $split = array();
    foreach (preg_split('/,(?=1\b)/', $string) as $row => $part1) {
        foreach (explode(',', $part1) as $part2) {
            list($key, $value) = explode('=>', $part2, 2);
            $split[$row][$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $split;
}
```

Tested as follows (in php 5.6):

```
$string = "1=>10,2=>9,3=>7,1=>9,2=>8,3=>7";
$split = split_string($string);
var_dump($split);
```

Gives this output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "9"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [1]=>
    string(1) "9"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "8"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
}
```

You could then use `array_combine()` for example to merge in the names:

```
$string = "1=>10,2=>9,3=>7,1=>9,2=>8,3=>7";
$split = split_string($string);
var_dump(array_combine(array('Build Quality', 'Versatility'), $split));
```